# Svelte react on dependency change rather than mere dependency assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, svelte

I'm having trouble with too much reaction that is causing expensive operations (like database queries) to be repeated unnecessarily when there has been no change to any dependencies.

Is there a way in Svelte to request reaction ONLY when a dependency has **changed** its value? With $:, Svelte reacts on **assignment** even if the assignment didn't change the value.

I find myself constantly coding reams of "lastVariableValue" type variables and manually comparing them to the new variable values and blocking reactive execution from proceeding further if there are no changes. This leads to a lot of what I feel like are rather unnecessary variables to store last values.

```
let lastCurrentDateMode
let lastNodeName
let lastModelEntityId

$: (currentDateMode !== lastCurrentDateMode || entityNode?.name !== lastNodeName || modelEntity.modelEntityId != lastModelEntityId) && runQuery()

async function runQuery() {
  // do expensive query

  lastCurrentDateMode = currentDateMode
  lastNodeName = entityNode.name
  lastModelEntityId = modelEntity.modelEntityId
}
```

It seems like there should be some way of telling Svelte to do this for us... react only if a dependent variable actually changes. That would reduce the above to just two lines of code.

Another method is to build my own conditional execution wrapper and use it everywhere throughout my code. Something like:

```
export const callfx = (_old, _vars, _function) => {
  if (Object.values(_vars).every(val => typeof val !== "undefined") && Object.entries(_vars).some(([name,val]) => JSON.stringify(_old[name]) !== JSON.stringify(val))) {
    _function.call()
  }

  Object.assign(_old,_vars)
}

// and imported into another component, where it used:

const _old={}
$: callfx(_old,{currentDateMode,entityNode,modelEntity},runQuery)
```

This works and reduces the burden to one variable declaration per component (_old) and a single call line, but it feels like I'm trying to do something that should be built into the framework itself.

Comment: What version of svelte are you using?

Comment: per npm, version 3.53.1

Comment: A combination of Svelte derived stores and Svelte Readable stores seems like a good candidate for what you're trying to achieve. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/69935945/13021392